# Java - MongoDB Compund Index Text Search

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using MongoDB latest version 2.12 Java Driver, in Eclipse. However, even after extensive searching on SO as well as Google, I could not resolve my problem.
Here is my code snippet:

```
mongoClient_m = new MongoClient();
db_m = mongoClient_m.getDB("atlascompare");
coll_m = db_m.getCollection("CollRMOB");

    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("ErrorName", "RMOB RULE_INFO")
                    .append("ErrorCause", "Database Out Of Sync")
                    .append("Resolution", "Try clearing your cache, or check database ver")
                    .append("TechnicalDat", new BasicDBObject("Java Null Pointer", 203).append("Java File Not Found Exception", 102)); 
    coll_m.insert(doc);
                    doc = new BasicDBObject("ErrorName", "ERROR X_2609")
                    .append("ErrorCause", "CAUSE X_2609")
                    .append("Resolution", "PERFORM X_2609")
                    .append("TechnicalDat", new BasicDBObject("Java X_2609_1", 203).append("Java X_2609_2", 102)); 
    coll_m.insert(doc);
                    doc = new BasicDBObject("ErrorName", "ERROR Y_2609")
                    .append("ErrorCause", "CAUSE Y_2609")
                    .append("Resolution", "PERFORM Y_2609")
                    .append("TechnicalDat", new BasicDBObject("Java Y_2609_1", 203).append("Java Y_2609_2", 102)); 
    coll_m.insert(doc);
```

Here is the output I get on printing the docs:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53e306577bdc3279309da4e3"} , "ErrorName" : "RMOB RULE_INFO" , "ErrorCause" : "Database Out Of Sync" , "Resolution" : "Try clearing your cache, or check database ver" , "TechnicalDat" : { "Java Null Pointer" : 203 , "Java File Not Found Exception" : 102}}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53e306577bdc3279309da4e4"} , "ErrorName" : "ERROR X_2609" , "ErrorCause" : "CAUSE X_2609" , "Resolution" : "PERFORM X_2609" , "TechnicalDat" : { "Java X_2609_1" : 203 , "Java X_2609_2" : 102}}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53e306577bdc3279309da4e5"} , "ErrorName" : "ERROR Y_2609" , "ErrorCause" : "CAUSE Y_2609" , "Resolution" : "PERFORM Y_2609" , "TechnicalDat" : { "Java Y_2609_1" : 203 , "Java Y_2609_2" : 102}}
```

However a simple text search does not show any output!!

```
BasicDBObject textSearch = new BasicDBObject("$text", "ERROR X_2609");
BasicDBObject search = new BasicDBObject("$search", textSearch);
System.out.println(coll_m.find(search));
```

Prints the following lines:

```
Cursor id=0, ns=atlascompare.CollRMOB, query={ "$search" : { "$text" : "ERROR X_2609"}}, numIterated=0, readPreference=primary
```

Can anybody please guide me what I am doing wrong?!

Edit 1: Also, I made sure the indexes were made. Here is the output when I print the indexes:

```
Indexes present ----------------------------
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "_id" : 1} , "name" : "_id_" , "ns" : "atlascompare.CollRMOB"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "_fts" : "text" , "_ftsx" : 1} , "name" : "$**_text" , "ns" : "atlascompare.CollRMOB" , "weights" : { "$**" : 1} , "default_language" : "english" , "language_override" : "language" , "textIndexVersion" : 2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that your query is not correct.

The query should look like: (in the MongoDB Shell)

`db.CollRMOB.find( { $text : { $search : "ERROR X_2609"  } } );`

So in your Java code it should be something like:

`BasicDBObject textSearch = new BasicDBObject("$search", "ERROR X_2609");
 BasicDBObject search = new BasicDBObject("$text", textSearch);
 // the print the documents
 System.out.println(coll_m.find(search).toArray()  );`

Tug

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Had been banging my head around it for nearly 16 hours....!! Made my day......Seems like a pretty silly mistake to me now...